# Before_request for multiple Blueprints

Tags: python, flask

Here's my situation:

Let's say I have 2 Blueprints before_request method:

```
mod = Blueprint('posts', __name__, url_prefix='/posts')

@mod.before_request
def before_request():
  #some code that uses SQLAlchemy here 
  pass
```

Now I don't want to duplicate the logic in this method in the second blueprint.

How can I do this?

PS: I'm new to Python so I might be missing something obvious.
Thanks.

Comment: You can always define these functions elsewhere, `import` them and do `mod.before_request(imported_function)`

Comment: I knew I was missing the obvious. Thanks :)

Comment: Damn .. now I don't have access to the g object from flask

Comment: Are you designing a user authentication or role system? If so, take a look at [Flask-Security](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/).

Comment: @Blender - Thank you. It wasn't working because I didn't import g ... damn beginners :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [`blueprint.before_app_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_request) which applies to views app-wide, not only views in the same blueprint

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it's what I want but still ... what if I have 2 blueprints that need to process something while other 2 blueprints that need to handle something else ?(maybe one needs admin rights and the other needs user rights)

Comment: @sirrocco what do you mean? you should define user privilege level elsewhere, and do `before_request`s by that user level

Comment: I was looking for the answer that Blender gave in the comment above :) .Thanks.